# Can't edit a document created by another user in Firestore (Vue.js / Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Thanks ahead for any help, this has been driving me bonkers!

I am following the firestore data model where users can create their own documents, which are attached to their userID as to ensure that users can only create and see requests that they've created.  However, I have a admin that needs to access and edit requests submitted by those users.

So far I have been able to get access to the subcollection via collectionGroup('subcollection').  Although it does return the documents, if I try to update or delete any one of them (besides those I've created myself as admin), it returns an *uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update* error.

HTML:

```
<!-- Add New Request -->
<input
  type="submit"
  @click="addRequest"
  value="Save and Add"  
/>

<!-- Update Past Request -->
<button
  @click="updateRequest()"
  type="button"
  v-if="modal == 'edit'"
  >Update
</button>

<!-- Delete Past Request -->
<button
  @click="deleteRequest(request)"
  type="button"
  v-if="modal == 'edit'"
  >Delete
</button>

<!-- Set return objects -->
data() {
  return {
      requests: [],
      request: {
        //Standard
        req_assigned: null,
        req_contact: null,
        req_status: null,
        timestamp: null
      },
  }
}

<!-- Firestore Assign -->
firestore() {
  const user = fb.auth().currentUser;

  return {
    requests: db.collection("uzers").doc(user.uid).collection("requestz"),
    uzers: db.collection("uzers").doc(user.uid),
    bulksettings: db.collection("bulksettingz")
  };
},
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Add New Request 
addRequest() {
  this.$firestore.requests.add(this.request);
}

// Update Past Request
updateRequest() {
  this.$firestore.requests.doc(this.request.id).update(this.request);
},

// Delete Past Request
deleteProduct(doc) {
  this.$firestore.requests.doc(doc.id).delete();
},
```

THE ERROR:

```
index.cjs.js?e89a:350 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/vue-shop-276c4/databases/(default)/documents/uzers/k0yZFhDbldVpf6FhhPMcykK5GJD3/requestz/9ET8nk53MxBx3JlhZqKx
    at new FirestoreError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js:350:28)
```

So again, just to recap, I am trying to edit and delete requests added by other users.  This has haunted me for quite some time now.  A big thank you to anyone that can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a set of firebase rules to control access to the documents, there is an example here in the documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access?authuser=0

Comment: Hi, and thank you for helping.  Here is the rub, my security rules are totally open at the moment (testing).  I'm starting to wonder if maybe I need a docRef sort of process.  Not sure, still trying to figure this out.  Thank you again.